# Why is the order of the difference operator defined as $p$ rather than $p+1$ for the second order differential equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading the book *Discrete Variable Methods in Ordinary Differential Equations* (1962) by Peter Henrici. I am confused about the accuracy definition in multistep method for the second order differential equations (Page 296). Why is the order of the difference operator defined as $p$ rather than $p+1$ which had been defined for the first order differential equation (Page 221). And how are these two accuracy definitions consistent with each other as the high order differential equation can be reduced to the first order differential equations?

The accuracy definition of the difference operator for the fist order differential equation:
$$L[y(x);h]=\alpha_ky(x+kh)+\alpha_{k-1}y(x+(k-1)h)+...+\alpha_0y(x)-h\{\beta_ky'(x+kh)+\beta_{k-1}y'(x+(k-1)h)+...+\beta_0y'(x)\} $$
and expansion:
$$L[y(x);h]=C_0y(x)+C_1hy'(x)+...+C_qh^qy^{(q)}(x)+... $$
The difference operator is said to be of order $p$ if $C_0=C_1=...=C_p=0$, but $C_{p+1}\neq0$.

The accuracy definition of the difference operator for the second order differential equation:
$$L[y(x);h]=\alpha_ky(x+kh)+\alpha_{k-1}y(x+(k-1)h)+...+\alpha_0y(x)-h^2\{\beta_ky''(x+kh)+\beta_{k-1}y''(x+(k-1)h)+...+\beta_0y''(x)\} $$
and expansion
$$L[y(x);h]=C_0y(x)+C_1hy'(x)+...+C_qh^qy^{(q)}(x)+... $$
The difference operator is said to be of order $p$ if $C_0=C_1=...=C_{p+1}=0$, but $C_{p+2}\neq0$.

Comment: Are you sure that this question should be asked here instead of math.stackexchange? About the question itself: What are $k$, $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$ and $C_i$? I recommend trying to make your question more self-contained, since not everyone has the book.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I will ask this question in math.stackexchange and add more detailed information to make the question self-contained.